# Laravel: Count rows with relationships tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, count, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables who are related.

### settlements:

| id | reon_id | name |

### add_members:

| id | settlement_id | first_name | last_name | cipher_id |

In Settlement Model their related like this:

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AddMember');
}
```

So, first I need all members with reon_id of 1, so I did like this:

```
$members = Settlement::where('reon_id', '1')
  ->with('members')
  ->count();
```

and that works. But now, I need same thing but also with cipher_id of 1. If I add ->where('cipher_id', '1') after ->with('members') I get this error:

(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cipher_id' in 'where clause'

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) to query properly the related table.

```
$members = Settlement::with('members')->whereHas('members', function($query){
      $query->where('cipher_id', 1);
})->where('reon_id', '1')->count();
```

**Explanation**

[WhereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) only takes the parent which met the condition inside. In this case no settlements will be shown if the related model member cipher_id not 1

Comment: But, then is missing where reon_id == 1 in settlement table? This way just showing me where cipher_id == 1...?

Comment: My bad, but you just have to add it

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks @Luis felipe De jesus Munoz ;)

Comment: Good. Keep it going